# Problem with CGImageDestination and file naming

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios4, core-graphics

I am capturing images from the camera, using AVCapture as I have need of speed and the standard kit stuff is way too slow.
I have problem whereby the file that is being output (an animated GIF) is having it's file name mangles by the CGImageDestination functions...

When I output the NSURL (cast to a CFURLRef) to the log I get the path/filename I intended:

```
2011-09-04 20:40:25.914 Mover[3558:707] Path as string:.../Documents/91B2C5E8-F925-47F3-B539-15185F640828-3558-000003327A227485.gif
```

However, once the file is created and saved it actually lists the filename as this:

```
2011-09-04 20:40:25.960 Mover[3558:707] file: .91B2C5E8-F925-47F3-B539-15185F640828-3558-000003327A227485.gif-TtNT
```

See the difference? the period at the start and the 4 character suffix?
Whats really wierd is that it doesn't *always* do it, about 40% of the time it works OK. However it's preventing the code working further down the line where I'm listing them with previews in a table view.

Does anyone know why and how to stop it doing this?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)exportAnimatedGif{

NSString *guidPath = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
NSString *tmpPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:guidPath];
NSString *path = [tmpPath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"gif"];
NSLog(@"Path as string:%@", path);
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], kUTTypeGIF, [captureArray count], NULL);

NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:testDisplay3.displayValue]                                   forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
                                                            forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
NSDictionary *gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                               [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount, 
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:testDisplay3.displayValue], (NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime, 
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:testDisplay3.displayValue], (NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime,
                                nil]
                                                          forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
for (int ii = 0; ii < [captureArray count]; ii++) 
{
    UIImage *tmpImg = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    tmpImg = [captureArray objectAtIndex:ii];
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, tmpImg.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
}
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);

//TEST OUTPUT GENERATED FILES
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] error:nil];
for (int xx = 0; xx < [contents count]; xx++) 
{
    NSLog(@"file: %@", [contents objectAtIndex:xx]);
}
//END TEST CODE
[captureArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: Add a debug line to see how many paths are being returned from `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` You're accessing this method twice and the second time it could be returning a different obsolete path. This function can return more than one path and I don't think there's any guarantee about what order they'll be in. Try accessing the first object rather than the last. Also make sure you only access this function once at the beginning and store the path in an ivar. That way you're guaranteed of getting the same path twice.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is a temporary file that `CGImageDestinationFinalize` makes,  the reason you see them is that `CGImageDestinationFinalize` failed. I think that if you check the  file sizes you'll see that the ones with mangled names have a file size of 0.

I started check for succes after I got these files :)

```
bool success =  CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"animated GIF file created at %@", path);
} else {
    NSLog(@"failed to create gif at %@", path);
}
```