# Objective C: "_kUTTypeGIF", referenced from error while implementing GIF images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Im going to implement gif images using the link http://gist.github.com/mayoff/4969104

I have added imageIO & CoreImagesFrameWorks

include following files

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

i have faced an issue while implementing line may be

```
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeGIF, kFrameCount, NULL);
```

Error is:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

**"_kUTTypeGIF", referenced from:**

```
  _makeAnimatedGif in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: That is part of `MobileCoreServices.framework`.  Are you linking against it?

Comment: I have found some link for you. Please let me know are they helpful or not. Link 1-[here](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/07/save-cgimageref-as-jpeg2000/) Link 2-[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225838/save-cgimageref-to-png-file-errors-arc-caused) Link 3- [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556516/save-cgimageref-as-jpeg2000) Link 4-[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301718/problem-with-cgimagedestination-and-file-naming) Also make sure that either you have .gif file if you are referencing it from `ViewController.m`, and it should be also included to bundle resource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386